# Is there a way to extract only the string of a paragraph when webscraping in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

We want to know if there is a way to extract only the string of a paragraph when web scraping in python?

The problem lies in our definition of 'price'

Anastacia <3

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scraper(url):
    url.status_code
    url.headers
    c = url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
    samples2 = soup.find_all(class_="product-price font-weight-bold mb-0")
    for p in samples2:
        price = (p)

    
        print(price)
        print()


url = "https://www.bevco.dk/spiritus/"
url = requests.get(url)
scraper(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to modify the variable **price**. Extract the text from between the tags and for esthetic purposes, strip the extracted string.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scraper(url):
    url.status_code
    url.headers
    c = url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
    samples2 = soup.find_all(class_="product-price font-weight-bold mb-0")
    for p in samples2:
        price = (p)
        print(price.get_text().strip())
        print()


url = "https://www.bevco.dk/spiritus/"
url = requests.get(url)
scraper(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
  
def getdata(url): 
    r = requests.get(url) 
    return r.text 
htmldata = getdata("https://www.bevco.dk/spiritus") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser') 
data = '' 
for data in soup.find_all("p",{'class': 'product-price font-weight-bold mb-0'}): 
    print(data.get_text()) `enter code here`
```

Comment: Hey Mohammad. Thanks for the answer. We want to extract the string of only paragraphs with class = "product-price font-weight-bold mb-0"

Comment: for data in soup.find_all("p",{'class': 'product-price font-weight-bold mb-0'}): 
    print(data.get_text())

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks again Mohammad. We're sorry to ask you once again, but would it be possible to define price as the data.get_text value instead of printing it directly? We would like to print it in  print(txt.format()) alongside our other variables. I hope you'll be able to help